# Taking a sample of the image dataset

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

For example i want to develop a Deep Learning model for classification of images and I have thousands of images . Since training the model with the whole dataset takes a long amount of time i would like to take a sample (10%) of the original dataset for initial training . How to do this?

Comment: Please leave aside hypothetical discussions ("*for example*"), and describe *precisely* your *exact* issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dataset is contained into a folder, I will try in the following:

```
import os 
import numpy as np

images = os.listdir('Path to your dataset') # list of all the images
n_test_images = int(len(images) * 0.1) # 10% of the total images

subset_images = np.random.choice(images, size=n_test_images, replace=False)
```

I used replace=True to avoid picking twice the same element.
After I selected the 10% of the images, I load them.

Actually I am not sure if this way is the most optimal one, but it could be a good starting point.